# Find $\int\frac{(1+x^2)dx}{1-2x^2\cos\alpha+x^4}$ ,where $\alpha\in(0,\pi)$

Tags: integration

$\int\frac{(1+x^2)dx}{1-2x^2\cos\alpha+x^4}$ ,where $\alpha\in(0,\pi)$

---

Let $I=\int\frac{(1+x^2)dx}{1-2x^2\cos\alpha+x^4}$
$I=\int\frac{(1+x^2)dx}{\sin^2\alpha+(x^2-\cos\alpha)^2}$
But there seems no way to solve it further.So tried another method.
 $I=\int\frac{(1+x^2)dx}{1-2x^2\cos\alpha+x^4}$
Put $\cos\alpha=1-2\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})$
$I=\int\frac{(1+x^2)dx}{1-2x^2(1-2\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2}))+x^4}$
$I=\int\frac{(1+x^2)dx}{1-2x^2+4\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})x^2+x^4}$
$I=\int\frac{(1+x^2)dx}{(1-x^2)^2+4x^2\sin^2(\frac{\alpha}{2})}$
But i could not solve it further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

$$I=\int\dfrac{1+x^2}{1-2x^2\cos\alpha+x^4}dx=\int\dfrac{1/x^2+1}{1/x^2-2\cos\alpha+x^2}$$

As $\displaystyle\int\left(\dfrac1{x^2}+1\right)dx=x-\dfrac1x,$ set $x-\dfrac1x=y$

$$I=\int\dfrac{1/x^2+1}{(x-1/x)^2+2-2\cos\alpha}$$

$$=\int\dfrac{dy}{y^2+\left(2\sin\dfrac\alpha2\right)^2}$$

Now as $\alpha\in(0,\pi), \sin\dfrac\alpha2>0$